# C# Remove collection (1, 2) from Collection (1, 2, 1, 2, 3). Expected result is: (1, 2, 3)

Tags: c#

Has any built-in function to do that?
Assume that i have list A List{1, 2, 2, 3, 4} and list B List{2, 3}. And a function List NoName(A, B). I expected the return value of NoName is {1, 2, 4}. I guess function Except can do that, but not.
I can't find out any words to explain my problem. But i can explain by pseudo code.

```
foreach(item in B)
{
    A.RemoveAt(A.IndexOf(item))
}

return A
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will increase the chances of getting proper response.

Comment: Without reasonable explanation what do you mean "remove collection" (like first two item, all/one element from first collection, something else) this question is not answerable.

Comment: Please see my expected result and inputs.
inputs (1, 1, 1), (1) => Expected result : (1, 1)
Inputs (1, 2, 3), (2) => Expected result: (1, 3).
...

Comment: What you want is subtracting two sets. In your example `A - B`

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary, can you give me an example, i tried but haven't any method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments, I think you want something similar with [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx), but only applies to the first appearance of the subset.

An unclear thing is: what if B is not a subset of A? What's the result of {1, 2, 3} - {3, 5}?

Obviously there is no built-in function to achieve this.

```
static IEnumerable<int> RemoveFirstSubset(int[] super, int[] sub)
{
    //omitted code to check parameters

    var index = 0;
    var found = false;

    while (index < super.Length)
    {
        if (!found && super.Skip(index).Take(sub.Length).SequenceEqual(sub))
        {
            found = true;
            index += sub.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return super[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! thank you for your help. "Enumerable.Except, but only applies to the first appearance of the subset" <== this is my problem :).
I can write my own function, but i think C# has a function to do that.
This is my code:



private static IEnumerable<T> MyExcept<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
        {
            var arr = a.ToList();
            foreach (var item in b)
            {
                arr.Remove(item);
            }

            return arr;
        }